Docker file takes 6 minutes to build, not sure why
Here's my dockerfile:
FROM node:22.7.0

# Set environment variables early
ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true \
    CHROME_PATH="/usr/bin/google-chrome"

# Install dependencies in one layer to minimize image size
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends ffmpeg chromium && \
    ln -s /usr/bin/chromium /usr/bin/google-chrome && \
    apt-get clean

# Copy package files and install dependencies
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Copy the rest of the project files
COPY . .

# Start the application
CMD ["yarn", "run", "serve"]

It still takes 6 minutes in GCP.
This is my cloudbuild:

steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest"
    args:
      - --destination=${_LOCATION}-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/${_REPOSITORY}/${_IMAGE}
      - --cache=true
  - name: "gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk"
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args:
      [
        "run",
        "deploy",
        "${_SERVICE}",
        "--image",
        "${_LOCATION}-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/${_REPOSITORY}/${_IMAGE}",
        "--region",
        "${_LOCATION}",
      ]

options:
  default_logs_bucket_behavior: REGIONAL_USER_OWNED_BUCKET

substitutions:
  _SERVICE: my-app
  _LOCATION: us-central1
  _REPOSITORY: cloud-run-source-deploy
  _IMAGE: my-app

Looking at the logs I see a lot of time passes without logs after printing
Step #0: INFO[0083] Found cached layer, extracting to filesystem 


Do you have more metrics? In addition, I know that chromium is pretty heavy to install, it  could be the issue. Remember that, by default, your Cloud Build run on a single CPU and you can easily saturate it!

@guillaumeblaquiere I expect it to be slow on the first run, but after that shouldn't it be cached?

@JorgeMontejo added some info

It's serverless. A new instance is created at every build on Cloud Build. There is no context, no cache. The advantage is that you do not pay for cache! The bad news is you have to build your container with kaniko is you want cache feature (and the cache is stored on Cloud Storage, and therefore you pay for it! Nothing is magic! or free) https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/optimize-builds/kaniko-cache

@guillaumeblaquiere I don't follow. I read this guide and thought I followed it correctly, but it's still pretty slow.

Did you run 2 builds in a row? The second is not faster?

@guillaumeblaquiere correct, 5-6 minutes is the best i could get to
